# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] PaperClip Error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Paperclip is working fine on my localhost but when I am trying to upload images on my server, I am getting this error (as shown in my production.rb log file)

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
```

I am very surprised why this is happening. I have not put any :url or :path in any model since anyway it is working fine on localhost without it (I see some of the other answers suggesting that but I am not sure this is the problem). Any one with suggestions on how to fix this paperclip problem ?

EDIT - Ok, while creating a page which has attachment and when I am uploading image, the image is not uploading, I am getting the error above and the image of the path is http://example.com/system/photos/preview_images//original/home.png?1369929849, see the two //, why is this so ? there should be 000/000/004 or something like this there, right ?

Answer (score 1):

If your server is using ssl, you might have to use url instead of path. It works fine in localhost because your localhost will not be using ssl.

For example

=link_to "something", some_path

should be replaced with

=link_to "something", some_url

Comment: Hi, no, I am using ssl on server, This is certainly only paperclip problem IMO

Comment: http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2009/8/29/protecting-your-paperclip-downloads might help.